# Pivot SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table like this (of course there are many more values but you get the idea):

```
ID      Name
---     ----
1       A
1       B
2       C
3       D
4       A
4       D
4       E
4       F
4       G
4       H
```

I want to write a query that would output this, given that an ID cannot have more than 6 names.

```
ID      Name1        Name2       Name3     Name4     Name5    Name6
---    ------        ------     ------    ------    ------    -----
1        A             B
2        C
3        D
4        A             D           E         F         G        H
```

Comment: @Lwoodyiii - I found a fault in my response.  I don't think it will extrapolate up to 6 - suggest you extend your question slightly to give the full picture.

Comment: @Martin I edited it.  Please put your answer back up, I think it could be extended to the correct answer.  I thought it was a useful start.
Thanks!

Comment: It didn't work - _fatally_ flawed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
WITH rows AS (
   SELECT t.id,
          t.name,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY t.name) 'rank'
     FROM TABLE t)
  SELECT r.id,
         MAX(CASE WHEN r.rank = 1 THEN r.name ELSE NULL END) AS Name1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN r.rank = 2 THEN r.name ELSE NULL END) AS Name2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN r.rank = 3 THEN r.name ELSE NULL END) AS Name3,
         MAX(CASE WHEN r.rank = 4 THEN r.name ELSE NULL END) AS Name4,
         MAX(CASE WHEN r.rank = 5 THEN r.name ELSE NULL END) AS Name5,
         MAX(CASE WHEN r.rank = 6 THEN r.name ELSE NULL END) AS Name6,
    FROM rows r
GROUP BY r.id
```

Non CTE equivalent:

```
SELECT r.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.rank = 1 THEN r.name ELSE NULL END) AS Name1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.rank = 2 THEN r.name ELSE NULL END) AS Name2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.rank = 3 THEN r.name ELSE NULL END) AS Name3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.rank = 4 THEN r.name ELSE NULL END) AS Name4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.rank = 5 THEN r.name ELSE NULL END) AS Name5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.rank = 6 THEN r.name ELSE NULL END) AS Name6,
  FROM (SELECT t.id,
               t.name,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY t.name) 'rank'
          FROM TABLE t) r
GROUP BY r.id
```

Reference:

- [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I created a stored procedure named pivot_query to make the PIVOT statement a little more flexible. The source for it is [here](http://dot-dash-dot.com/files/pivot_query.sql). There is also an [example](http://dot-dash-dot.com/files/pivot_query_examples.sql) of how to use it.

Borrowing a piece of code from OMG Ponies below, and changing the query a bit,
then the call to pivot_query would look like this:

```
declare @mySQL varchar(MAX)

set @mySQL = '
SELECT
   t.id,
   t.name,
   ''Name'' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY t.name) as varchar(2)) rank
FROM
   TestData t'

exec pivot_query @mySQL, 'Id', 'rank', 'max(Name)'
```

and the results now look like this:

```
Id         Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 Name5 Name6 
---------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- 
1          A     B     NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  
2          C     NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  
3          D     NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  
4          A     D     E     F     G     H
```

Not exactly sure what you're trying to show, though. :-)

This will not intrinsically limit the output to the 6 name columns though, it will keep going up unless you add a where clause to specifically exclude ranks above 6.

Comment: Close, but no cigar.  I don't want G & H to show up  in Name_7 and Name_8 column, but in Name5 and Name 6 column.  I also don't want to have to put in the Names in the test data table.